# SQL Server: Using date in ISO 8601 format in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework-core

In SQL Server 2014 I tried the following query:

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where StartDate = '2021-12-31T00:00:00.0000000'
```

I get this error:

> Msg 295, level 16, state 3, row 3
> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

As far as I can tell this string is in ISO 8601 format, so it should be accepted by SQL Server (I read that this should actually be the preferred format when passing dates to SQL Server).

Is there a way to tell SQL Server to accept this format?

**Please note: this query is actually generated by Linq in an Entity Framework Core DataContext, so I can't change the query itself in any way.**

Comment: Reduce the precision of the time-of-day component as it's `smalldatetime`, not `datetime`:  `select * from MyTable where StartDate = '2021-12-31'`

Comment: That said, no-one should be using `smalldatetime` today. Why aren't you using `datetime2` ?

Comment: Thank you Dai. As I wrote, this query is generated from EF, so I can't modify it...

Comment: I'm saying you need to change your database design in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't look like EF Core generated query. EF Core generated query will use typed **parameter** which *is* "the preferred format when passing dates to SQL Server", i.e. passing them as dates rather than strings.

Comment: How is it created there ? What are the parameters that you can paste there (EF) ? Can you choose table-object ?

Comment: There is no way EF would generate such a query unless you passed in text. Parse it into a date in the client, then pass it *as an actual date*

Answer (score 0):

- [Older versions of EF Core did not support `smalldatetime`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12584).
- [This was fixed in version 2.2.0 in 2018](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13118).
- Update your EF Core version to something more recent than 2.2.0.
- If you *are* using a modern EF Core version, then you should file this as [a regression bug](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues).
- But better yet: **don't use `smalldatetime` in your database design in the first place**. Use `datetime2(n)` or some other appropriate type instead.

  - **There is no good reason for using `smalldatetime` in a new database design** ([nor other types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) like `text`, `ntext`, `image`, `timestamp`, etc)
  - And you should be able to run `ALTER TABLE` to change the column type to `datetime2(7)` with no compatibility issues unless something else is *really horribly designed* in your system, in which case you should fix that.
  - If you *really* need to expose data as `smalldatetime` because of some horrible and opaque, but business-critical, binary that you can't rebuild then you can add a `VIEW`, `SYNONYM` and other shims to transparently convert `datetime2(n)` to `smalldatetime` while the rest of the system can live in modernity.